# Can we add a list as a value to sorted set in redis?

Tags: python, list, redis, sortedset

I am trying to create a sorted set of lists based on a score. Something like:

```
li="li"
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['a','d','e']
redis.zadd(li,1,list1)
redis.zadd(li,2,list2)
```

Can we do this or what is the way to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you tell us the output that you want ? I mean exact output

Comment: The exact output is to retrieve the top ten lists (lists with top ten scores)

Comment: Redis' nested data structures only contain strings (so no, you can't have a Redis List in a Redis Sorted Set, but you can serialize the list to a string and store that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to retrieve the top 10 list you can do this

create a set for each list and add setId to the sorted set

```
redis.sadd(setId, ...setElements)
redis.sadd(setId, ...setElements)
redis.sadd(setId, ...setElements)

redis.zadd(key, score, setId)
redis.zadd(key, score, setId)
redis.zadd(key, score, setId)
redis.zadd(key, score, setId)

redis.zrange(key, 0, 10) # get the top 10 setId (only the key names)
```

if you would like to get the data as well, you can create a pipeline and call `smember` for each keyId

Comment: So the set Elements can be lists?

Comment: in the example code you have there, it's string right?

Comment: The idea is that store the data in another data structure and just add the key name to the sorted set.